# How remove two specific characters from param from url NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

i have this url xxxxx.com/xxxx/xx-xx-2/xxxx and want remove the "-2" from second parameter in the url and that it stays that way xxxxx.com/xxxx/xx-xx/xxxx, The "-2" is random. i don't have idea how to do it :( any help would appreciate it.

My apologies for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You should add below

```
location ~ /[^/]+/[^/]+-[\d+]/ {
      rewrite ^/([^/]+/[^/]+)-[\d+]/(.*) $1/$2 redirect;
}
```

In a url `/part1/part2-number/` The `/[^/]+` matches `/part1`, `/[^/]+` matches `/part2` and `-[\d+]/` matched `-number` and then your rewrite it to remove the number

Test Results:

```
$ curl -I localhost/tarun/lalwani-2/abc
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 11:44:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Location: http://localhost/tarun/lalwani/abc
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I localhost/tarun/lalwani-10/abc
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 11:44:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Location: http://localhost/tarun/lalwani/abc
Connection: keep-alive
```